# Geoserver DWITHIN Error

Tags: geoserver, javascript, leaflet

Currently passing a Geoserver cql_filter to leaflet with a form and button but getting an error of "ReferenceError: DWITHIN is not defined" returned back from the browser when clicking the button my function is attached to.

My function is in a seperate javascript file:

```
    //Pylon Search Button
    function updatePylons() {
            var pylonFilter = DWITHIN(geom,collectGeometries(queryCollection('Inyaninga_243-198:proposed_pylons_3857','geom',"id = '" + document.getElementById("Pylon").value + "'")),0.05,kilometers);
            return proposed_pylons.setParams({CQL_FILTER:pylonFilter});
    };
```

The form in the html:

```
<form>
    Pylons:<br>
    <input type="text" id="Pylon">
    <input type="number" id="distance">
    <input type="button" value="Filter" onclick="updatePylons()">
```

Anyone had any experience with this? The form parameters are meant to pass to the cql_filter as user input and then update when the button is clicked. However, the DWITHIN is not defined error occurs when clicking the button.

Comment: Is DWITHIN a javascript function in your code base?

Comment: Hi there yes it is in my code base.

Comment: Please share the full request being sent to Geoserver. Or is it not even reaching that point?

Comment: I have managed to get past the undefined DWITHIN error, however now when I query my WMS layer is completely removed as soon as I click the button my function is attached too.

Comment: The Geoserver request is: GET /geoserver//wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=Inyaninga_243-198%3Aproposed_pylons_3857&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&height=256&width=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&CQL_FILTER=DWITHIN(geom%2C%20collectGeometries(queryCollection(%27Inyaninga_243-198%3Aproposed_pylons_3857%27%2C%27geom%27%2C%27id%20%3D%20%27%27EP1%27%27%20%27))%2C%205000%2C%20meters)&bbox=3502650.384139917,-3473298.56527841,3512434.3237604196,-3463514.625657907 HTTP/1.1

Comment: @CamMullerAnd if you open that request in a separate browser tab, what do you get? An image, an error message...?

Comment: @IvanSanchez If i pass that request to a new tab I get the error message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bounding box coordinate 0 is not parsable:350??2650.384139917
Bounding box coordinate 0 is not parsable:350??2650.384139917

Answer (score 2):

By copy-pasting the URL that you copy-pasted into your comments, I noticed that your request is full of zero-width unprintable characters:

[image]

`E2 80 8C` is the UTF8 sequence for the unicode code point U+200C, which is `ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER`, and `E2 80 8B` is `ZERO WIDTH SPACE`.

There is *something* in your code adding those control characters every 22 characters in the URL string. Find that, set it on fire (figuratively), and the problem *should* disappear.